# Set Data Validation in doPost not applied to data until after posting

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet where I import data from a collection form using a doPost function.  I was getting several copies of each record so I added a data validation rule to the script that requires the imported record ID not already be in the spreadsheet.  The rule is not working to eliminate duplicate posts as written.  It does not get applied to a record at the time it is posted.  Instead, it gets set in the record when a new record is inserted above it.  How can I fix this to apply the rule to validate the data before it posts?

Here is my script...

```
//https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz6LGmlBb0IXW2TMBL1CZNHvLzGDSCywDH8gwmmX_e3nd2bXdU/exec

function doPost(e) 

{var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1dLC9b3-LhGeS0QznOGw-cy0w1TrGBhCyY1e74raTZqQ');
var target = sheet.getSheetByName('iForm Data').getRange('B2');
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireFormulaSatisfied('=ISERROR(MATCH({B2},{B3:B},0))').setAllowInvalid(false).build();
target.setDataValidation(rule);

{if (typeof e !=="undefined")

{var iFormPostTable = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1dLC9b3-LhGeS0QznOGw-cy0w1TrGBhCyY1e74raTZqQ");
var dSheet = iFormPostTable.getSheetByName("iForm Data");                
var pSheet = iFormPostTable.getSheetByName("XML Post");                 
var tSheet = iFormPostTable.getSheetByName("Web Service Transactions");  

var key = "audits";

var postResult = e.parameter

var keyResult = postResult.audits;

pSheet.getRange("A2").setValue(postResult);
pSheet.getRange("B2").setValue(keyResult);

if (keyResult.length > 0)
{var xmlDoc = Xml.parse(keyResult, true);

function _getElement(xmlTag, xmlDoc)
{

 var xmlRecords = xmlDoc.getElement().getElements('record');

try {
return(xmlRecords[0].getElement(xmlTag).getText());
} catch (e) {
return(e.message);
}
}

dSheet.insertRowAfter(1);
dSheet.getRange("A2").setValue(Date());
dSheet.getRange("B2").setValue(_getElement("ID", xmlDoc));
dSheet.getRange("C2").setValue(_getElement("audit_date", xmlDoc));
dSheet.getRange("D2").setValue(_getElement("route", xmlDoc));
dSheet.getRange("E2").setValue(_getElement("stop", xmlDoc));
dSheet.getRange("F2").setValue(_getElement("store_number", xmlDoc));
dSheet.getRange("G2").setValue(_getElement("concept", xmlDoc));
dSheet.getRange("H2").setValue(_getElement("city", xmlDoc));
dSheet.getRange("I2").setValue(_getElement("state1", xmlDoc));
dSheet.getRange("J2").setValue(_getElement("auditor", xmlDoc));
dSheet.getRange("K2").setValue(_getElement("selector", xmlDoc));
dSheet.getRange("L2").setValue(_getElement("pallet_initial", xmlDoc));
dSheet.getRange("M2").setValue(_getElement("selection_zone", xmlDoc));
dSheet.getRange("N2").setValue(_getElement("steak_date", xmlDoc));
dSheet.getRange("O2").setValue(_getElement("tomato_date", xmlDoc));
dSheet.getRange("P2").setValue(_getElement("lettuce_date", xmlDoc));
dSheet.getRange("Q2").setValue(_getElement("cilantro_date", xmlDoc));
dSheet.getRange("R2").setValue(_getElement("chicken_date", xmlDoc));
dSheet.getRange("S2").setValue(_getElement("errors", xmlDoc));
dSheet.getRange("T2").setValue(_getElement("shorts", xmlDoc));
dSheet.getRange("U2").setValue(_getElement("list_shorts", xmlDoc));
dSheet.getRange("V2").setValue(_getElement("overages", xmlDoc));
dSheet.getRange("W2").setValue(_getElement("list_overages", xmlDoc));
dSheet.getRange("X2").setValue(_getElement("mispicks", xmlDoc));
dSheet.getRange("Y2").setValue(_getElement("list_mispicks", xmlDoc));
dSheet.getRange("Z2").setValue(_getElement("corrected", xmlDoc));
dSheet.getRange("AA2").setValue(_getElement("out_of_stock", xmlDoc));
dSheet.getRange("AB2").setValue(_getElement("list_outs", xmlDoc));
dSheet.getRange("AC2").setValue(_getElement("pallet_rework", xmlDoc));
dSheet.getRange("AD2").setValue(_getElement("reasons_for_rebuild", xmlDoc));
dSheet.getRange("AE2").setValue(_getElement("rebuild_number", xmlDoc));
dSheet.getRange("AF2").setValue(_getElement("total_number", xmlDoc));
dSheet.getRange("AG2").setValue(_getElement("additional_info", xmlDoc));

tSheet.insertRowAfter(2);
tSheet.getRange("A3").setValue(Date());
tSheet.getRange("B3").setValue(key);
tSheet.getRange("C3").setValue("Data Posted");

 var response = ContentService.createTextOutput();
response.setContent("Post received!");
return(response);
} else {

tSheet.insertRowAfter(2);
tSheet.getRange("A3").setValue(Date());
tSheet.getRange("B3").setValue(key);
tSheet.getRange("C3").setValue("Invalid Key Attempt");
}
}  
}
}
```

Comment: If you have the formula, why not validate the new data in your script, before you write the possibly-duplicate record to the sheet?

Comment: Where in your code is the if-statement that does "data validation rule to the script that requires the imported record ID not already be in the spreadsheet."?

Comment: The "if" statement is built in to the formula which requires that an error occurs when trying to match the imported record ID (B2) to the record IDs already in the sheet (B3:B).

Comment: And I finally figured out to do just that, tehhowch.  I tried several places in the script before I got it to work.  It turns out if I put the validation rule into the script immediately after dSheet.insertRowAfter(1) I don't get duplicates.  I'm very new to this and I keep forgetting that the program does exactly what you tell it to do, including the order! Problem solved - set the data validation rule after the record is trying to add data to the sheet but before the value for the cell it applies to is posted and it works, just the way I told it to.